# Angle between position and velocity vectors is constant?

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, parametric, curvature

Is there a name for such a curve or can this even happen? I know when the velocity vector, $\mathbf{x'}$, and position vector, $\mathbf{x}$ are always orthogonal $\mathbf{x}(t)$ parametrizes a circle so I thought maybe in general it forms a spiral. But this is only an inkling.

The only equation I have relating two vectors and their angles is the standard $$\cos(\theta)=\frac{|\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{x'}|}{||\mathbf{x}||||\mathbf{x'}||}$$
 I tried converting this to polar, but I don't understand how to relate the notion of angle between $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{x'}$ in that context.

Comment: @Neal: But that's a very different question.

Comment: @TedShifrin True, I'll take that back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When expressed in polar form, the components of velocity are $\frac{dr}{dt}$ along the radius and $r\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ tangentially.
Therefore if the velocity vector makes constant angle $\alpha$ with the radius vector, we have $$\tan\alpha=\frac{r\frac{d\theta}{dt}}{\frac{dr}{dt}}=r\frac{d\theta}{dr}$$
solving, we have $$\frac{1}{r}dr=\cot\alpha d\theta$$
this leads to the general solution $$r=ae^{\theta\cot\alpha},$$ which is indeed a spiral.

Note that when the velocity is perpendicular to the radius vector, $\cot\alpha=0$ which leaves us with the circle $r=a$.

Comment: Example: A charged particle in a uniform magnetic field.

Comment: Could you explain how you got $\frac{r d\theta}{dt}$ in first paragraph? Also, I don't understand why the tangent of the angle between position and velocity is $tan^{-1}(\frac {y}{x}) $where $y,x$ are components of the velocity vector as it is above... finally, don't straight lines also satisfy the conditions above?

Comment: @ FTem...the position vector is $$\underline{r}=\left(\begin{matrix}r\cos\theta\\r\sin\theta\end{matrix}\right)$$by definition, the velocity is $$\underline{v}=\frac{d\underline{r}}{dt}$$

Comment: I don't understand why can we use tangent here? I thought to find the angle between two vectors you use the cosine equation?

Comment: so $$\underline{v}=\frac{dr}{dt}\left(\begin{matrix}\cos\theta\\ \sin\theta\end{matrix}\right)+r\frac{d\theta}{dt}\left(\begin{matrix}-\sin\theta\\ \cos\theta\end{matrix}\right)$$ showing the radial component as $\frac{dr}{dt}$ and the tangential component as $r\frac{d\theta}{dt}$